# INDEX to pull multiple criteria

Tags: excel, formula

I am putting together a directory of information for Hotels. My goal is to pull information from different worksheets. I normally would just do a vlookup but there is obviously multiple hotels in one city.

I need it to pull data for all options. EX( if Phoenix, AZ is listed 3 times I need to pull it from the data to show three options). Once I have the multiple cities listed I then need to pull address, phone, hotel name, and the rate for each one.

**data**:

[image]

right now, I have been messing around with this formula

`{=INDEX(range, MATCH(lookup_value_1&lookup_value_2&..., lookup_range_1&lookup_range_2&..., match_type))}`

it is not doing what I want it do when I am adjusting with my criteria.

I am kind of lost on this, I have never worked with an index formula to this degree and pulling the information from different worksheets.

Comment: Look into Advanced Filter

Comment: I have to pull this information into a different worksheet, they will be searching different cities each time they use it. I also have to pull the information into a separate tab. I don't think that will work for what I need to do

Comment: You can use Advanced Filter to pull to a different worksheet, the criteria and the starting the Advanced Filter must be on the target sheet, then refer back to the data sheet.  A sheet full of Array Formulas will slow everything down.  If you have access to the new dynamic array formulas then you can use `=FILTER(D:H,D:D = "Phoenix, AZ")`

Comment: If not, then move to Google sheets where they have `Filter` already.

Comment: great, thank you! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> The same have been answered through comment by @Scott Craner, and
>   accepted by Q_Auth @Sam.

You can use Advanced Filter to pull to a different worksheet, the criteria and the starting the Advanced Filter must be on the target sheet, then refer back to the data sheet. A sheet full of Array Formulas will slow everything down. If you have access to the new dynamic array formulas then you can use `=FILTER(D:H,D:D = "Phoenix, AZ")`

If not, then move to Google sheets where they have `Filter` already.

> Note:Answered The Question Through Comment, Hence the same was opened
>   question. Now answering behalf of @Scott to close the question.